# JavaFX filter ListView File elements using FileFilter

Tags: java, search, javafx, filefilter

I hava JavaFX application which shows all folders of a specific directory and watches for new/deleted folders and updates the `ListView`.

Now I'm trying to let the user filter/search the folders using a `TextField`.
I've done that before, so this is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // configure other stuff
    configureListView();
}

private void configureListView() {
    searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        handleSearchOnType(observable, oldVal, newVal);
    });
    // more stuff here
}

private void handleSearchOnType(ObservableValue observable, String oldVal, String newVal) {
    File folderToSearch = new File(config.getDlRootPath());
    ObservableList<File> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(folderToSearch.listFiles(
            pathname -> pathname.isDirectory() && pathname.getName().contains(newVal))); // something seems wrong here?!
    if (!searchField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        listView.setItems(filteredList);
    } else {
        // nothing to filter
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            folderToSearch.listFiles(pathname -> pathname.isDirectory())));
        }
    }
```

This gives me strange results, e.g.:

[image: no search]
[image: search for 'test']

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

My custom cell factory

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<File>, ListCell<File>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<File> call(ListView<File> list) {
                return new ListCell<File>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(File t, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(t, bln);
                        if (t != null) {
                            setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("img/folder.png")));
                            setText(t.getName());
                        }
                    }

                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: Instead of checking `!searchField.getText().isEmpty()` can you try `!oldVal.isEmpty()` ?

Comment: Didn't fix it, nothing changed.

Comment: Random guess: do you have a custom cell factory? If so, can you post it? (My hunch is you're not properly handling empty cells...). (As an aside, you'll potentially get better performance by just keeping a reference to the filtered list and updating its predicate, instead of creating a new list.)

Comment: I added the custom cell factory code to my post

Comment: OK, that is at least part of the problem... it might not be all the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only thing wrong, but your custom cell factory needs to handle the case where the cell is empty:

```
final Image image = new Image("img/folder.png");

listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<File>, ListCell<File>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<File> call(ListView<File> list) {
        return new ListCell<File>() {
            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(File t, boolean bln) {
                super.updateItem(t, bln);
                if (t == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                    setText(t.getName());
                }
            }

        };
    }
});
```

The point here is that when you start filtering, some cells which previously were not empty will become empty. `updateItem(null, true)` will be invoked on those cells, which need to then clear all their content (otherwise they just keep the content they had before).

(For a bonus, I also refactored slightly so that you don't keep loading the image from the image file in every cell, every time the user scrolls the list view.)

Comment: Great! This was the only problem, now it works as it should. Thanks